# Trying to grep after a specified string

Tags: regex, grep

So I have a large file with a collection eBooks, each with labels like `Title: The Book Title (That may-contain 'special_characters)`. I have the following grep command in order to match everything after the `Title:` string along with the proceeding space to get all the book titles:

```
grep -P -o '(?<=^Title:\s).*' ebooks_full.txt
```

But it's not working and returning a bunch of blank lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data that is generating this behavior?  Your `grep` command works just fine for me with the single sample title provided in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got Windows line endings in your ebooks, so every match ends with a `CR`. On Linux, that will effectively cause the line to be printed and then immediately deleted, so you won't see it on your output.

Easy solution: eliminate the `CR` from the match:

```
grep -P -o '(?<=^Title:\s)[^\r]*' ebooks_full.txt
```

Alternative solution: tell `grep` not to colorise the output:

```
grep --color=no -P -o '(?<=^Title:\s).*' ebooks_full.txt
```

(However, that will leave the CRs in place, so use the first solution if you want to capture the output into a file.)

Better technical explanation: CR (carriage return) causes the cursor to be moved to the beginning of the line. `grep -o` (when it is outputting in color) puts an `ESC [ K` sequence at the end of each line, which erases the screen to the end of the line.

Comment: Sharp eye - I don't often immediately think of the vagaries of moving data between Windows and Linux platforms.  :)